# How to add thing by specific index in arraylist in java without raise IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        temp.add(0,"123");
        temp.add(3,"123");
    }
}
```

result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 1
```

I know I can just use `.add("String")` to add anything I want in arraylist without caring about index. However, what I want is to add `"String"` in specific index. Is there any way to do so without raising IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you know what the size of the ArrayList should be? If so, just use an array. This isn't how a List should be used. If you really really want to do this, you could add a bunch of nulls...

Comment: As @JeremyHeiler said I think that for that propose you should consider a Map (Hashmap) instead of ArrayList or an array.

Comment: @CaioLopes I think Hashmap perfectly resolve my problem. Can you answer the question below so I can give the best answer to you? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest for your propose to use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

It allows you to add key-value elements so you don't need to bother with IndexOutOfBoundsException.

A example on how to use it can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the index where you want the new String to be is OutOfBounds or not, for example:

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    temp.add(0,"123");
    int index = 3;
    if (temp.size() > index){
        temp.add(index,"123");
    }
```

When it is OutOfBounds you can create a larger ArrayList or add it to a lower indexNumber.